Understanding AM/FM stereo receiver schematic
I am working on a parts list to build a AM/FM Stereo receiver (see https://electronics-diy.com/pdf/TEA5711.pdf).  It's a design from Phillips Electronics using the TEA5711 IC.  It was published in 1994.  In reviewing the schematic, I see some components that aren't clear to me. Hopefully you can help answer the following questions:
a) In my attached picture, I've circled L1 through L4.  I'm not completely sure what component this is. Is this some type of fixed inductor? On page 20 of the datasheet, it is typed as the AM-AERIAL. It then describes the following:
ferroceptor
length = 6 cm
L1-2 = 625 µH
N1-2 = 105 turns
unloaded Q
If this is a component are individual parts that I need, I'm not sure what to ask for from a electronics parts supplier.  Can you explain?
b) L2 is the RM-RF.  It describes:
L1-2 = 66 nH
N1-2 = 2.5 turns
unloaded Q = 150T
TOKO type S18
TOKO number 301SS-0200
I'm not sure what unloaded Q means or the number/letter associated with is.  I've not been able to find much on TOKO S18 or the TOKO number of 301SS-0200.  Can you advise what all of this is?
c) The dotted line at the potentiometer seems to indicated these a ganged.  Am I correct?

Image source: Fig.8 Application circuit of TEA5711 from Philips Semiconductors TEA5711 datasheet linked above

These are variable inductors. Their variable element is ferrite or iron-powder ceramic formed as threaded slugs whose position inside a copper coil can vary inductance. Sometimes, a slug is formed from threaded brass or aluminum - used at higher frequency. Inductors are not ganged together...they are individually adjusted. I doubt very much that L1 is truly adjustable...this is usually a ferrite rod antenna. Its coil might adjust by sliding toward one end of the ferrite rod.

look at the dashed line ... it connects to the variable capacitors

L1 is the ferrite-rod antenna coil for AM broadcast-band reception.
A 140pf variable capacitor resonates with this inductor at the bottom-end of the AM broadcast band (0.54 MHz to 1.6 MHz).
Notice that 625 uH ferrite-rod inductor in parallel with 140 pf resonates at 0.538 MHz. For a particular-size ferrite rod of a certain permeability, 105 turns around the rod gives roughly 625 uH.
For the FM broadcast band, inductance of 66 nH seems about right to resonate with a 20pf parallel capacitance. However, calculating resonant frequency is only approximate, because stray inductance and stray circuit capacitances are significant error sources.
In some cheap radios, these coils are air-wound, and their inductance is adjusted by stretching or distorting their shape. If you make your own coil, you'd need more than 2.5 turns if no tuning core was used, or else you could wind it on a larger diameter coil form.
TOKO is a component parts manufacturer based in Japan, who makes (made) radio-frequency component product lines. Be aware that radio construction has moved on from these rather old designs where specially-made coils and capacitors are required. Try searching TOKO 301SS-0200. You may actually find a distributor who'll sell you small quantities. 
Q is quality factor - of particular interest for inductors, whose inductance is tainted by undesired resistance. Q is ratio of inductive reactance to resistance at a particular frequency...a high Q quality factor is desired in tuned resonators.
